# How to install Parallel Tools Platform into my existing Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, parallel-processing, openmp, eclipse-cdt

Hi guys I'm using OS X right now. It seems like I can't compile my parallel code with default clang in OS X so I decided to install the Parallel Tools Platform into my Eclipse, which I use to write Java.

The problem is that I can't find the right package named Parallel Tools Platform in the Eclipse Market Place. What's the name of that package?

I've already downloaded the CDT but have no idea where the parallel tools are. Can someone help me with this please?

Thank you.

Another question is since the default clang doesn't support openMP, I installed g++ but when compiling it still can't find `<omg.h>`, so I have to use Eclipse. How to use g++ or clang compile openMP in OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find instructions for adding it into your existing install at https://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/release_notes/8.0#Install_PTP . Maybe use a different Question for your second question.